# Trying to Download Xubuntu, but don't have dvd

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to ditch xp on my old computer, so I decided to switch it over to Xubuntu, which is supposed to be great for older hardware. However, I don't have a DVD-R available at this time. Is it possible to split the installation between multiple disks, as is done for large video games and the like?

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu.com. Installing any linux distro is possible with USB sticks as well. In fact your question may be duplicate, so for future reference, try researching a question before posting.

Answer (score 1):

[See our help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) for a list of options on installing without a CD. Some will not be possible for your specific machine and others might be difficult.

> **Installation without a CD**
>
> The new generations of laptops and netbooks are increasingly shipping
>   without CD drives. To cater to this need, or if you do not wish to
>   burn a CD to install Ubuntu, you are not left to trudge in the dark -
>   Ubuntu can be installed without using a CD or CD-ROM drive!
>
> [Quick Install from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick) - A quick guide to installing from a USB
>   memory stick. Intended for less technically-inclined readers.
>
> [Install from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) - Installing from a USB memory stick (full
>   version).
>
> [USB stick + grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromCForUSBStick) - Similar to above but using grub.
>
> [Smart Boot Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SmartBootManager) - Installing from a PC which will not boot
>   from a CD.
>
> [Install within Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows) - Yes, it is possible to install Ubuntu
>   from within Windows without using floppies, a CD, or any other
>   removable media! This uses Wubi, and installs Ubuntu as a large file
>   that may be uninstalled like any other program in Windows.
>
> [Install with Floppies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/WithFloppies) - Installing without a CD drive over a
>   network.
>
> [Install From Hard Drive with Floppies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromHardDriveWithFloppies) - Installing without a CD
>   drive or network capabilities from a hard drive.
>
> [Install from Existing Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux) - Installing using a spare partition
>   from an existing Linux system to house the Ubuntu CD image.
>
> [Virtual Machine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromVM) - Installing using a physical disk to a Virtual
>   Machine.
>
> [Portable installed system booting from UEFI & BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS) - A system
>   for a USB pendrive - a good alternative to a persistent live system.

---

> Is it possible to split the installation between multiple disks, as is done for large video games and the like?

As you can see from the above links the answer is no. If it is just a lack in DVD-Rs I would get some and use those. Some of these options are difficult and require a more than average amount of expertise. Fun when tinkering; annoying when you have to get something running.

If you want to try lUbuntu out now use a virtual system inside XP. You can have that up and running quickly with no hassle at all and wait for your DVDs to arrive.